# Ajax 500 Internal Server Error?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Maybe its a dublicate but every Situation is different :)

I get a String from Ajax Request and handle it to this function

```
function convertHashtags($str){

    $text = $str;
    $regex = '/#(\w+)/';
    preg_match_all($regex, $text, $allMatches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
    foreach ($allMatches as $matches) { 
        $engine->checkHashtag($matches[0]);
    }

    $regex2 = "/#+([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/";
    $str = preg_replace($regex2, '<a href="hashtag.php?tag=$1">$0</a>', $str);
    return($str);
}
```

Then i want in the for each that for every Result the Engine is inserting it to Database.
When i comment out the Engine line then its working. 
return $matches[0]; is working too!

This is my Engine function code

```
function checkHashtag($tag) {
    return true;
}
```

And at least here is my Error Message...

> 500 (Internal Server Error)send
>
> @ jquery-1.10.2.js:8706jQuery.extend.ajax
>
> @ jquery-1.10.2.js:8136(anonymous function)
>
> @ (index):797jQuery.event.dispatch
>
> @ jquery-1.10.2.js:5095jQuery.event.add.elemData.handle
>
> @ jquery-1.10.2.js:4766

Why is it not working ?

***What is $Engine ? ***
A included Class

```
require_once('../PATH/engine_class.php');
$engine = NEW engine_class();
```

Comment: What is $engine, looks like a object but its not instantiated anywhere?? Certainly not within the scope of that function

Comment: $engine is a included class :) i will edit my Question

Comment: Check your server error logs, they will tell you the reason for the 500 error. Chances are it's because `$engine` is not within the scope of your function.

Answer (score 0):

preg_match_all returns an int, holding the number of matches. I note that you don't check to see if there were 0 matches. Your code assumes that there is at least one valid match. What value is returned from the routine?

Comment: I see no such assumption. If there are no matches, OP's code will just return `$str` unmodified.

Comment: perhaps I'm missing something important, but this link: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php has the following note: on Return Values 
Returns the number of full pattern matches (which might be zero), or FALSE if an error occurred.

Comment: Yes, that's correct but OP isn't assuming anything about the number of matches. If there are no matches, then `$allMatches` will be an empty array, zero `foreach` iterations will run and `preg_replace` will change nothing.

Comment: I've run into a few places in php where a variable like $allMatches was not an empty array, but a null and encountered the 500 error as a result of that. I agree with your point, but am unclear as to what php actually returns for that variable when there are no results.

Comment: An empty array, trust me. The only time it would be different is if there was an error and that's irrelevant in this case.

Comment: To feed this talking a bit. I got where i echo 1 time my return from my Function   the Result -> 1

Comment: right. so this is a scoping issue within the foreach, so change it to an anonymous function along the lines of: 
foreach ($allMatches as $matches) { 
        $engine->checkHashtag($matches[0]);
    }

Comment: alright, that didn't take, let's try it again: add an anonymous function along the lines of: 
foreach ($allMatches as $matches) { function ($_matches) {$engine->checkHashtag($_matches);}($matches[0])}
That way the scoping is preserved and the function executed in the foreach correctly executes against the right value.

Comment: oh, duhh! thanks. It doesn't help to mix javascript with php. The issue is where is "engine" defined. It's not defined within the convertHashtags routine, so it's an unknown variable when convertHashtags encounters it. Add one line to the top of your function, immediately after the first curly brace "{": 
    global $engine;
This will enable the convertHashtags to know about the (previously defined) $engine variable.